# Javascript not executing google chrome extensioin

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new in google chrome extensions and I need to develop a popup that let search some text that is inside the popup, I've followed this tutorial: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html

This is the html code of popup.html, it works in the navigator but when I load the extension the popup appears but when I click in find the text is not highlighted.

```
<script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript" > </script>
<input type="text" id="search">
<input type="button" id="button"   
onmousedown="doSearch(document.getElementById('search').value)" value="Find">

<div id="content">
<p>Here is some searchable text wsdith some lápices in it, and more lápices, and some
```

**for*mat*t**ing

And the popup.js is the following:

```
    function doSearch(text) {
      if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
          document.designMode = "on";
          var sel = window.getSelection();
          sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

          while (window.find(text)) {
              document.getElementById("button").blur();
             document.execCommand('hiliteColor', false, 'yellow');

              sel.collapseToEnd();
          }
          document.designMode = "off";
      } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
          var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
          while (textRange.findText(text)) {
              textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, "yellow");
              textRange.collapse(false);
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: You have inline javascript, it's not allowed. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution . Put all your JS code into a separate file.

Comment: Thanks, I edited but it still don't work... maybe is the permissions in manifest.json?

Comment: Sorry, you can't have `onmousedown` - it's still inline JS. Anyway, try inspecting popup and debugging this yourself (right click on the toolbar icon -> Inspect Popup).

Comment: Have you checked console for errors??

Comment: I checked the console and I found: "Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:"

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things. You can't inline your javascript, so you should change to:

```
var input = document.getElementById('button');
input.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    doSearch(document.getElementById('search').value);
});
```

And the `designMode` commands are case sensitive. Change the following line:

```
document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, 'yellow');
```

to:

```
document.execCommand('hiliteColor', false, 'yellow');
```

Though I don't understand why you've got the feature detection if this is only for a Chrome extension, you'll want to change that command to `backColor` as well.

Comment: You still have inlined javascript... its the `onmousedown` attribute of your input element. You need to change this to an event handler like I've done in my edit